# Do I have a problem with the IBM MQ dependency?

Tags: python, node.js, docker, ibm-mq, node-gyp

i have this error when i upload my repository to Jenkis, i does not detect the ibm mq library it sends me the following error, i have not been able to fix it.

attached error.

```
     Copying blob sha256:97518928ae5f3d52d4164b314a7e73654eb686ecd8aafa0b79acd980773a740d
Copying blob sha256:884acb06399854759d90ca69f71f6ba3d3be88de193ec78501d4e57a517ca7d9
Copying blob sha256:a3930deb173dc6fe50792f24f5a7b18b7b35e5483cc2200d3ee3781663078fc8
Copying config sha256:37a1b854e294c8d6e1b0519b02e7ab3e991194dde8bb9004ccf8f230fb40bf81
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
Adding transient rw bind mount for /run/secrets/rhsm
Adding transient rw bind mount for /run/secrets/etc-pki-entitlement
Adding transient rw bind mount for /run/secrets/redhat.repo
STEP 1: FROM node:16-alpine3.14
STEP 2: WORKDIR /usr/src/app

STEP 3: COPY package*.json ./
--> ee1cee5da5a
STEP 4: RUN npm install
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.3.1 -> 8.5.2
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.2>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.5.2` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/node_modules/ffi-napi
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/ffi-napi
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-03T19_33_05_255Z-debug-0.log
error: build error: error building at STEP "RUN npm install": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

I have been researching this problem in different places, to see if I can find a solution to this.

I leave the links below.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/153)

Comment: For me the only solution that worked was to install Python3 manually and add it to the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the nested dependency `node-gyp` requires python.

From https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/282

```
RUN apk update && apk add python g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

though as you are basing on a node image you might just be able to get away with

```
RUN apk update && apk add python
```

Alternatively you can take a look at this sample `Dockerfile` - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/Dockerfile

Comment: OR, if python is installed, maybe it's just not available in the PATH or via env variable of the agent node, as noted in the error message. Agent launched via SSH do not source the user's profile, only the default, as they are non-interactive logins.